# Change field by my own field in Sharepoint Online

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a lookup column and when I add new item, I need to display the lookup information into a drop down list with search bar, i found a plugin that allows me to display the list as I want but I need to replace the default list of lookup by my own list and I don't know how to do it (I don't know the code to insert it).

In preference, by using javacript and JQuery.
Thank you

This is the javascript that i use to have a autocompleted dropdown list

```js
   

   $( function() {

     $.widget( "custom.combobox", {

       _create: function() {

         this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )

           .addClass( "custom-combobox" )

           .insertAfter( this.element );

  

         this.element.hide();

         this._createAutocomplete();

         this._createShowAllButton();

       },

  

       _createAutocomplete: function() {

         var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),

           value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

  

         this.input = $( "<input>" )

           .appendTo( this.wrapper )

           .val( value )

           .attr( "title", "" )

           .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )

           .autocomplete({

             delay: 0,

             minLength: 0,

             source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )

           })

           .tooltip({

             classes: {

               "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"

             }

           });

  

         this._on( this.input, {

           autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {

             ui.item.option.selected = true;

             this._trigger( "select", event, {

               item: ui.item.option

             });

           },

  

           autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"

         });

       },

  

       _createShowAllButton: function() {

         var input = this.input,

           wasOpen = false;

  

         $( "<a>" )

           .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )

           .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )

           .tooltip()

           .appendTo( this.wrapper )

           .button({

             icons: {

               primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"

             },

             text: false

           })

           .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )

           .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )

           .on( "mousedown", function() {

             wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );

           })

           .on( "click", function() {

             input.trigger( "focus" );

  

             // Close if already visible

             if ( wasOpen ) {

               return;

             }

  

             // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results

             input.autocomplete( "search", "" );

           });

       },

  

       _source: function( request, response ) {

         var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );

         response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {

           var text = $( this ).text();

           if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )

             return {

               label: text,

               value: text,

               option: this

             };

         }) );

       },

  

       _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

  

         // Selected an item, nothing to do

         if ( ui.item ) {

           return;

         }

  

         // Search for a match (case-insensitive)

         var value = this.input.val(),

           valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),

           valid = false;

         this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {

           if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {

             this.selected = valid = true;

             return false;

           }

         });

  

         // Found a match, nothing to do

         if ( valid ) {

           return;

         }

  

         // Remove invalid value

         this.input

           .val( "" )

           .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )

           .tooltip( "open" );

         this.element.val( "" );

         this._delay(function() {

           this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );

         }, 2500 );

         this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";

       },

  

       _destroy: function() {

         this.wrapper.remove();

         this.element.show();

       }

     });

  

     $( "#combobox" ).combobox();

     $( "#toggle" ).on( "click", function() {

       $( "#combobox" ).toggle();

     });

   } );
```

```css
   .custom-combobox {

     position: relative;

     display: inline-block;

   }

   .custom-combobox-toggle {

     position: absolute;

     top: 0;

     bottom: 0;

     margin-left: -1px;

     padding: 0;

   }

   .custom-combobox-input {

     margin: 0;

     padding: 5px 10px;

   }
```

```html
  

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   

 <div class="ui-widget">

   <select id="combobox">

     <option value="Accessory">Accessory</option>

     <option value="Car">Car</option>

     <option value="Option">Option</option>

   </select>

 </div>
```

My script generate this code when i inspect element on I.E. *1

```html
<div class="ui-widget">

   <select id="combobox" style="display: none;">

     <option value="Accessory">Accessory</option>

     <option value="Car">Car</option>

     <option value="Option">Option</option>

   </select>
    <span class="custom-combobox">
      <input title="" class="custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
      <a tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-button-icon-only custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>
      </a>
    </span>

 </div>
```

This is the code of the default display of lokkup information on SharePoint *2

```html
<td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
  <!-- FieldName="Products"
    FieldInternalName="Products"
    FieldType="SPFieldLookup"
    -->
   <span dir="none">
       <select title="Products" id="Products_139d7cd0-706c-47fd-82fd-d532bae457c3_$LookupField">
          <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>
          <option value="2">Accessories</option>
          <option value="1">Cars</option>
          <option value="3">Options</option>
       </select>
       <br>
      </span>
</td>
```

And i need to replace de code *2 by the code *1

Example (i did it on paint):

[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/479ZJ.png)

[To this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbI6p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a custom form? if so you should use the ID from the dropdown to populate your custom plugin dropdown.
you should edit your ASPX file.

I just did this time ago.
Here is the code, de div class ui-widget is the container for the drop down with some CSS.
In your DOM is an ID from the original dropdown
Looks like:

```
ctl00_ctl44_g_*ID*_ff71_ctl00_Lookup
```

This ID is part of an select tag. In the select tag there are option's. with the ID you should get those options en place them in the plugin.

So figure out what kind of data the plugin accepts. Array? Select/option?

and convert the data from the ID to the needed data.

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <input id="nieuweKlant" type="button" value="Nieuwe Klant" onclick="openDialogEdit();" />
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Klant</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <input id="verversKlanten" type="button" value="Ververs Klanten" onclick="getListItem();" />
        <div class="ui-widget">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Klant" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Klant')}"/>
        </div>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff7description{$Pos}" FieldName="Klant" ControlMode="Edit"/>
        <input id="klantgegevens" type="button" value="Klantgegevens" onclick="openDialogEdit();" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What i need to know is how can i display my list instead of the default list in the default New Form. 

This is the select that i want to replace by my own select:
`<select title="Products" id="Products_139d7cd0-706c-47fd-82fd-d532bae457c3_$LookupField">`

And this is the select i want to display:
`<select title="Products" style="width: 300px;">`

I don't know how to code in javascript to say "when a select appears with title="Products" and id="Products_139d7cd0-706c-47fd-82fd-d532bae457c3_$LookupField", replace it by <select title="Products" style="width: 300px;">

Comment: I would use a custom form. This is more customizable.

The select: <select title="Products" style="width: 300px;">.
Is there a JS Script behind it? 
And if so could you maybe post the JavaScript inside the original post?

I use jQuery ui for this kind of stuff: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: I don't know if i can ask that on this forum but can i contact you personnaly on Skype or mail ? Cause i'm very very beginner so i need lot of helps and explanations i think.

Comment: What I would do and we all did is get to know the basic first. Code School and Code Academy are great place to start learning JavaScript. https://www.codeschool.com/ + https://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: Actually, i'm trying to replace a <select> by another <select> but i don't find solutions on internet.                                 
`<select id="Products">
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Option">Option</option>
</select>
<select id="combobox">
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Option">Option</option>
</select>` 
Those 2 selects and i want to replace first by the second one. But i can't do `$("#Products").replaceWith('#combobox');` how can i do this ?

Comment: I need context. So please always add you HTML, JavaScript code.

Comment: And you should not replace the ID. Make a new custom form and start editing the ASPX file.
The code snippet I send before is an example of an SharePoint formfield

Comment: I just did it if you don't understand or if some elements are missing, tell me

Comment: Before the script is generated in de DOM of your browser. It has some properties SharePoint reads and then converts to HTML in the browser. Make a Custom Form and you will find your form field that you want to change. Creating a custom form can be done in SharePoint Designer. The code will be the same as the code in my original post. This is where you can add divs and ID's

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to di this

Comment: I found on internet that we can add js.file directly in the code of the Form so i tried to add this code `<script src="https://bdbelux1.sharepoint.com/sites/studentday/bat/testJS/Shared%20Documents/jquery.txt" type="text/javascript"></script>` instead of the element that i want to replace but it doesn't work, the inspect element on I.E. show me that `<td width="400" class="ms-formbody" valign="top"><script src="https://bdbelux1.sharepoint.com/sites/studentday/bat/testJS/Shared%20Documents/jquery.txt" type="text/javascript"></script></td>`


But it doesn't display my list

Comment: I finally found how to do it, i replace the list in the NewForm by my own list and put Js on it with a Content Editor on SharePoint.


Big big thank to you for your help, without you, i couldn't do that ! :D

Comment: Great to hear that :) Could you maybe accept this as the answer? You can do this with the buttons next to my original post.